# Assembly::LoadFrom called from Managed C++ dll

Tags: c#, dll, managed-c++

I'm calling into a C# dll from a managed C++ application. The C# dll is going to be in a custom folder so I need the Managed C++ dll to dynamiclly load the C# from that folder.

This is all VC++ 2010 v100 and .net 4.0.

I intend to use

```
Assembly::LoadFrom("MyCSharp.dll")
```

I can see the LoadFrom call succeed and load the MyCSharp.DLL, however when a function within my managed C++ dll tries to access any of the functionality of that DLL, it either:

a) Fails if the MyCSharp.DLL is not present in the same executing folder as my application

b) Succeeds if MyCSharp.dll is present in the executing folder, however, now I've got two copies loaded into memory and I'm obviously not accessing the one loaded from my ::LoadFrom call.

I'm not sure what's preventing the executing function from linking against the explicitly loaded C#- dll.

I suspect its a possible configuration problem in the VC++ managed c++ dll that I'm unaware of.

Comment: I'm sure you mean C++/CLI, not Managed C++? Those are different languages and Managed C++ is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

If your Dll is in a subdirectory, you need to add that folder to the private path of the AppDomain. As far as i know, it can't be changed once the AppDomain is created, so you need to add it to the app.config by using the [`<probing> Element`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/823z9h8w%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Use [Assembly.AssemblyResolve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx) to retrieve your assembly which has already been loaded.